# Adding an object to Mutable array is not possible

Tags: objective-c

I am trying add a Song* object to a Mutable array and I am stumped as the count of the array is not increasing in spite of adding the object.

Song.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject

@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *title, *album, *artist;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *playTime;

@end
```

Song.m

```
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Song

@end
```

Playlist.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Song;

@interface Playlist : NSObject

@property(copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *playListArray;

-(void) addSong: (Song *) tempSongToBeAdded;
-(void) removeSong: (Song *) tempSongToBeremoved;
-(void) listOfSongs;
-(NSUInteger) entries;

@end
```

Playlist.m

```
#import "Playlist.h"
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Playlist

-(void) addSong: (Song *) tempSongToBeAdded{
    NSLog(@"%s song is being added.", [tempSongToBeAdded.title UTF8String]);
    [self.playListArray addObject:tempSongToBeAdded];
}
-(void) removeSong: (Song *) tempSongToBeremoved{
    [self.playListArray removeObject:tempSongToBeremoved];
}

-(NSUInteger) entries{
    return [self.playListArray count];
}


    -(void) listOfSongs{
        NSLog(@"Hi");
        for (Song *tempSong in self.playListArray) {
            NSLog(@"title: %s", [tempSong.title UTF8String]);
        }
    }

@end
```

Main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"
#import "Playlist.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    Song *song1 = [[Song alloc] init];
    song1.title = @"Manasa";
    song1.album = @"Ye Maya Chesava";
    song1.artist = @"A. R. Rahman";
    song1.playTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.56];

    Playlist *playlist1 = [[Playlist alloc] init];

    [playlist1 addSong:song1];
    NSLog(@"The total number of songs are %lu",[playlist1 entries]);
    [playlist1 listOfSongs];




    }
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the entries in the playlist as 0 and and the list of songs as empty. I am not getting any compile errors and I have no idea why the objects are not getting added to the array.

Comment: An oddity of Objective-C is that if you call a method using a nil pointer for the "object", the call returns nil/zero, without any error indication.  So you can "add" a dozen objects to your nil "array" and when you ask it will tell you that the count is still zero (since `[nil count]` always returns zero).

Comment: I am trying to init the array but when I am doing that I am getting a runtime error.

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray] alloc] init]` is giving you a runtime error??

Comment: Yes. http://imgur.com/159Jzlg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `playListArray` is never initialized and is always `nil`. You need to initialize it using:

```
playListArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];
```

You can add an `init` method in your `Playlist` class where you initialize this object.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        playListArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT:
The problem seems to be how you declared the property

```
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *playListArray;
```

It is declared as `copy`, that means that even when you do `playListArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init]`, your variable `playListArray` gets a copy of the initialized array, but the `copy` protocol is inherited from `NSArray`, not from `NSMutableArray`, so you get an immutable array. You can check this in the `NSMutableArray` documentation. You need to change `copy` for `retain` (you're not using ARC, right?).

In fact I see that you're using `copy` for most of your properties, if there's no particular reason for this, I would change them to `retain`.

Comment: I did that but I am getting a Runtime error in the addsong menthod. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001031a0`

Comment: It seems like you're initializing the object as `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Yes, `copy` is hardly ever used for properties that are object pointers.  Should only be used in special cases.

Comment: @HotLicks, @Morpheus: `copy` should be used for immutable objects with mutable subclasses. Have a look at [Encapsulating Data in Apple's "Programming with Objective-C" guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)